# On player change world give item with a delai - Minecraft - java

Tags: java, minecraft

I started to develop a plugin that would give items when a player changes world with 1 second of delay.

Otherwise the items did not appear in the player's hotbar.

A problem has arisen, IF during this second a second player also changes world, the items will only be given to one player (the one who changed world last).

*Bw: my server is is 1.14.4*

here is my code:

```
float timerCount = 1.0F;
@EventHandler
public void onWorldSwitch(PlayerChangedWorldEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    BukkitTask CountDownId;

    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    players.add(player);
    timerCount = 1.0F;
    CountDownId = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(plugin, new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            if(timerCount == 1.0F) {
                --timerCount;
            }
            else if(timerCount <= 0.0F) {
                int i = 0;
                player.sendMessage("Il est temps de te donner ton stuff");
                while( i <= players.size()) {
                    player.sendMessage("while loop");
                    plugin.giveStuff(players.get(i));
                    players.clear();
                }
                stopCountdown();
                timerCount = 5.0F;
            }
        }
    });
    player.sendMessage("world switch");
}
```

Give stuff :

```
public void giveStuff(Player player) {

    ItemStack compass = new ItemStack(Material.COMPASS);
    ItemMeta compassM = compass.getItemMeta();
    compassM.setDisplayName("§5Navigation");
    compass.setItemMeta(compassM);

    switch(player.getWorld().getName()) {
    case "lobby" :
        player.getInventory().setItem(0, compass);
        player.sendMessage("lobby");
        break;
    case "pvp":
        player.getInventory().setItem(0, compass);
        player.sendMessage("pvp");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming) page you can run an anonymous BukkitRunnable, which means without creating a new class with a name. Here is the code that I edited from yours. I couldn't test it since I don't have enough bandwith to download necessary files for opening a server. Hope this will work.

```
package net.example;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListener(this),this);
    }

}
```

and here listener class

```
package net.example;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerChangedWorldEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class MyListener implements Listener {

    private MyPlugin plugin; // A variable for your main method which extends JavaPlugin
    //Here we are getting instance of our plugin. We need this because BukkitRunnable have to be registered on a plugin.
    public MyListener(MyPlugin instance) {
        plugin = instance; //Saving Myplugin instance to our "plugin" variable
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onWorldSwitch(PlayerChangedWorldEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        // Create the task anonymously and schedule to run it once, after 20 ticks
        new BukkitRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // What you want to schedule goes here
                giveStuff(player);
            }
        }.runTaskLater(plugin, 20); //Run this task(all the commands within run() method) after 20 server ticks(1 second)
    }

    public void giveStuff(Player player) {
        ItemStack compass = new ItemStack(Material.COMPASS);
        ItemMeta compassM = compass.getItemMeta();
        compassM.setDisplayName("§5Navigation");
        compass.setItemMeta(compassM);

        player.getInventory().setItem(0, compass);
//        switch(player.getWorld().getName()) {
//            case "lobby" :
//                player.getInventory().setItem(0, compass);
//                player.sendMessage("lobby");
//                break;
//            case "pvp":
//                player.getInventory().setItem(0, compass);
//                player.sendMessage("pvp");
//                break;
//            default:
//                break;
    }
}
```

Some statements may conflict with OOP principles. This is done to increase clarity.
Let me know when you need more help.